# How to remove .html in htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, hyperlink

I have a problem removing the .html on the end of a page.
The code I use works perfectly accept on one page `/contact.html`.
If I rename the html file to anything else then `/contact.html` it works.
For an example `/nothing.html`.
If I add an empty html file on my server called contact.html it doesn't work either.

This is the code I use:

```
  RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{http://www.bijleshelmond.nl} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.html [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ http://www.bijleshelmond.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a folder (or even a file) named contact, you will need to remove that folder (or file first).

The condition is not met in this situation is one of the too:

```
# Condition broken if the directory 'contact' exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d


# Condition broken if the file 'contact' exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
```

Comment: Oh damn I didn't think of that.
I gonna rename that folder thanks!!